# Excel custom task pane with an XML layout

Tags: c#, excel, xml, visual-studio, customtaskpane

I'm creating a new custom task pane for Excel in C# by using Visual Studio. I followed the steps that I could find on the MSFT website and was able to create a ribbon button which shows/hides a blank task pane and this works well in Excel.

Now I have an xml file describing the buttons, user actions and api calls to a website and I know that everything works well with this one?

Is it possible to attach the xml file to the custom task pane that I have? When I open the task pane from the ribbon button, I want the pane to be loaded with the information from the xml file.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything about this and I start to believe that this is not possible.

Can someone please help?

Comment: "I want the pane to be loaded with the information from the xml file"?  You mean display the contents as text?  Or are you expecting it to automatically create buttons and api calls?

Comment: Xml file with buttons...  "everything works well with this one?"  What do you mean?

Comment: I don't want to display contents, but to create the buttons and api calls which are already defined in the xml file. By that sentence I mean that I'm sure that the xml file is correct, I just want to know if there is a way to load it into the pane.

Comment: You’d have to write code to read your xml and create controls which do what you want. There is no magic “make my app know what I want” method of solving this.